# In apply step, I explicitly want to ignore a few cells of a dataframe, but not able to do that

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my symmetric **DataFrame** I want to fill in values such that ans.loc[index, column] is the p-value result of two columns (these columns being 'index' and 'column') of separate DataFrame(adf).

My code:

```
adf = sports_team_performance().head(100)
sports = ['NFL', 'NBA', 'NHL', 'MLB']
ans = pd.DataFrame({k:np.nan for k in sports}, index=sports)

def p_map(row):
   sports = ['NFL', 'NBA', 'NHL', 'MLB']
   for x in sports:
       if row.name == x:
           continue
       else:
           row.loc[row.name, x] = stats.ttest_rel(adf[x], adf[row.name], nan_policy='omit')[1]
           print(row.name, x)
   return row

ans.apply(p_map, axis = 1)
```

Here **adf** has around 50 rows with indexes being **cities** and 4 columns: **['NFL', 'NBA', 'NHL', 'MLB']**
and the **ans** df is a **4x4 nan** df initally.

Now I'm using the above function and an using the apply step for above df.
My goal is **ans['NHL', 'NBA']** should be p-value of **NHL & NBA columns of my adf**
and **ans['MLB', 'MLB'] should be NaN**
The if else statement should ideally take care of that, and I'm using the print in the function to see if it is working well.
***Yet the entire DataFrame is getting populated***.

Output:

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L51Os.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `row.loc[row.name, x]` is a Series. And you are assigning the values of 2 sports to that series:

For example, after the first iteration, we know it continues to the next since `row.name` and `x` are `'NFL'` == `'NFL'`. Then the next iteration, `row.name` is `'NFL'` and x is `'NBA'`

[image]

`row.loc[row.name, x] = stats.ttest_rel(adf[x], adf[row.name], nan_policy='omit')[1]` is saying, "take the p-value, and put that in the Series of index row.name and index x (so `'NFL'` and `'NBA'`)"

[image]

What you really want is to just put it on index `'NBA'`, which is `x`. So to fix it, just lose the `row.name` in `row.loc`

**Code:**

```
adf = sports_team_performance().head(100)
sports = ['NFL', 'NBA', 'NHL', 'MLB']
ans = pd.DataFrame({k:np.nan for k in sports}, index=sports)

def p_map(row):
   sports = ['NFL', 'NBA', 'NHL', 'MLB']
   for x in sports:
       if row.name == x:
           continue
       else:
           row.loc[x] = stats.ttest_rel(adf[x], adf[row.name], nan_policy='omit')[1]   #<--- change made here
           print(row.name, x)
   return row

ans.apply(p_map, axis = 1)
```